# Pdx ANSI Intl language driver

Tags: sqlite, intl, paradox

is there a documentation about the old "Pdx ANSI Intl" language driver which is used in Borland Database Engine?

I would like to implement a custom Collate function for SQLite which compares strings in the same order with "Pdx ANSI Intl". Unfortunately I habe not found any document about this language driver and it's sort-order.

Thanks in advance.